# PHP: How to properly split a unicode Korean string?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a problem where I can't seem to be able to write "certain" Korean characters. Let me try to explain. These are the steps I take.

1. MS Access DB file (US version) has a table with Korean in it. I export this table as a text file with UTF-8 encoding. Let's call it "A.txt"
2. When A.txt is read, stored in an array, then written to a new file (B.txt), all characters display properly. I'm using `header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");` at the very beginning of my PHP script. I simply use `fwrite($fh, $someStr)`.
3. WHen I read B.txt in another script and write to yet a new file (C.txt), there's a certain column (obvisouly in the PHP code, I'm not working with a table or matrix, but effectively speaking when outputted back to the original text file format) that causes the characters to show up something like this: `¸ì¹˜ ì–´ëœíŠ¸ ë‚˜ì¼ë¡`. This entire column has broken characters, so if I have 5 columns in a text file, delimited by commas and encapsulated with double quotes, this column will break all of the other columns' Korean characters. If I omit this column in writing the text file, all is well.

Now, I noticed that certain PHP functions/operations break the Unicode characters. For example, if I use preg_replace() for any of the Korean strings and try to fwrite() that, it will break. However, I'm not performing anything that I'm not already doing on other fields/columns (speaking in terms of text file format), and other sections are not broken.

Does anyone have any idea on how to rectify this? I've tried `utf8_encode()` and `mb_convert_encoding()` in different ways with no success. I'm reading `utf8_encode()` wouldn't even be necessary if my file is UTF-8 to begin with. I've tried setting my computer language to Korean as well..

I've spent 2 days on this already, and it's becoming a huge waste of time. Please help!

- UPDATE: 
  I think I may have found the culprit. In the script that creates B.txt, I split a long Korean string into two (using string `...<br /><br />...` as indicator) and assign them to different columns. I think this splitting operation is ultimately causing the problem.
- NEW QUESTION:
  How do I go about splitting this long string into two while preserving the unicode? Previsouly, I had used `strpos()` and `substr()`, but I am reading that the `mb_*()` function might be what I need.. Testing now.

Comment: perhaps this would help: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: "I'm not performing anything that I'm not already doing on other fields/columns" - but *what* is it that you're doing?

Comment: Show us your code, if possible a complete, short, self-contained example demonstrating the problem. You're obviously doing *something*.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't phrase it better. I've put up the code so you can see it for yourselves. Please take a look.

Comment: You may be interested in [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 0):

Try the unicode modifier (u) for preg

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

u (PCRE_UTF8)
This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.